# hostgator vps, setup private name server

Tags: centos, vps

I'm trying to setup a private name serve on a hostgator vps account level 1. 
I found [this tutorial](http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-setup-private-dns-with-bind9-chroot-on-centos-6-2-vps/) how to do it.

In step 5 I have to start the named server with:

```
/etc/init.d/named start
```

which results in:

```
Starting named: named: already running                     [FAILED]
```

restart instead of start works.

then In step 7 I have to login to the second name server and change:

```
/var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf
```

but if I do change it it changes on both servers.

And last is when I'm checking if its been setup correctly in step 10 with:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

it results in 2 totally different ip's that aren't the same as I specified in earlier steps.

Any idea of how I can get my private name server up and running?

Tthe server uses CentOS 5.9